# Get list of the users with the top score for a given tag

Tags: support, tags, users

Given a certain "tag" in stackoverflow or any other stack exchange site, such as "c++", etc, how can one get for that tag a list with the users with the top total scores?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the tag and then select Top Users from near the top of the page

[image]

Or hover the mouse pointer over the tag and select Top Users from the pop out

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hover over the tag, then click `top users` in the opened menu. Or just go to ...

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/%the_tag_of_interest%/topusers