# Can we see user reputation by tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, users

Can we choose a tag and see what users have most reputation in this tag?

Example: A list of users that are ordered in a descending order by reputation gained with the tag `[ggplot2]`. This would show user that are best in `ggplot2`.

I ask just out of interest.

Comment: Not sure about reputation (there will probably be a few problems calculating that, with the daily reputation cap and such). But every tag has a [top users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159418/369802) bit, where you can see the top *scoring* users (which is just taking the post scores, which is upvotes - downvotes).

Comment: Cleaned up the comments, again. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74559/369802)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Click on a tag, click "Top users", a list of the top users in a tag is shown]

You can go to the tag page, and click on the 'users' link on the top. This will give you all-time top users, and top users in 30 days. It’s not 'reputation' - it’s 'score', so it doesn’t take into account repcaps and such, but it shows the user who's gotten the best aggregate score in the tag. Whether this is the 'best' user is a matter of some consideration, but it certainly tells you they're the most successful in posts with that tag.

Comment: What are the integers in the two columns with no column headers? https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers  I have no idea.

Comment: Score and posts. That it's not spelled out feels like a bug

Comment: Then I am confused again.  In the last 5 days, I've gained 65 rep points from answers to php-tagged questions.  How broken is this?  On Jan 22, I posted 1 necro-answer to a php-tagged question and got 55 rep from it.  Is the algorithm basing the "last 30 days" on the date of the question? I do a lot of necro posting.

Comment: That I have no clue about, and could br a question on its own