# Add column headers for "total score of { }" and "{ } answer(s) provided / question(s) asked" in the Top Users page

Tags: feature-request, statistics, top-users

After reading [Can we see user reputation by tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376056/352329), I wanted to see how I fared on my primary language tag on Stack Overflow.

I cannot make any sense of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers.

I'm clueless on what the column values represent -- because there are no column headings.

Please add column headings for "total score of { }" and "{ } answer(s) provided / question(s) asked" to the respective columns. It is possible to see what the statistics represent by hovering over each value, but hovering to see those tooltips is not possible on mobile.

Comment: They have title attributes: “total score of 16”, “42 answers provided”, respectively, under “Last 30 Days”.

Comment: The answer count looks accurate to me.  Why is the score only 16?  Is that badge points and not rep points or something?  Would more users be interested in seeing badge points? rep points? or both? ...in addition to answer count.

Comment: See the wiki for [[tag:score]]: it means upvotes minus downvotes

Comment: @mickmackusa my hypothesis was that score of 16 means that the total score of your answers is 16. So, same calculation as badge points: (total upvotes on answers) - (total downvotes on answers). I tested it by [looking up answers from last month](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2943403%20is%3aa%20created%3a1m) and [this was the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJi5c.png). The 42 posted answers matches but not the score. I count 4+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1=10. So, I don't know what 16 is. Possibly the number of upvotes only (haven't checked it)?

Comment: Update: I checked your 42 questions. None of them have mix of votes - the score you see on the screenshot corresponds exactly with the votes they got. I have no idea why you have score of 16 for the past 30 days.

Comment: OK...another update. My bad, the `1m` used for dates, checks the post *from last month*. Not *over the one last month*. Because we're in February, it will limit the answers from 1st of January to the 31st of January. [If I check for the answers from the last 30 days using a proper date range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2943403+is%3Aa+created%3A2022-01-11..2022-02-09+%5Bphp%5D) then I get 47 answers, which doesn't match the 42. However, the total score from the page is 15 which is closer to 16 (might be caching of a slightly earlier score).

Comment: I've necro-posted 6 new answers in the last 4 hours, so I'm a bit of a moving target now.  3am -- maybe I'll sleep.