# Under-labeled & Over-labeled Tables

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, top-users, tag-score

Any particular tag's Top Users page has some tables.  The Top Answerers (for the Last 30 Days and of All Time) and Top Askers (not shown) are listed along with two columns of numbers:

[image: Top Answers table, with edit marks]

These tables are *under-labeled*; the numbers columns are presumably for Score and Answers/Questions, but this is not clear.

**These tables should have unit headers for the number columns (as marked).**

---

Conversely, in a user's Profile page there is a table of Top Tags:
[image: Top Tags table, with edit marks]

This table is *over-labeled*; with the units for each number unnecessarily spelt out for every row.

**This table should have unit headers for the number columns rather than repeating the units.**

---

While *over-labeling* is better than *under-labeling*, it is unnecessary and aesthetically displeasing; it's a bad design for displaying information.  At the very lease it's inconsistent.

Comment: The under-labeled part would be a duplicate of [Add column headers for "total score of { }" and "{ } answer(s) provided / question(s) asked" in the Top Users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376087/add-column-headers-for-total-score-of-and-answers-provided-questi)

Answer (score 1):

Although your arguments are valid I look at the current choices of placing the labels as correct. Using 1920x1080 resolution I'll try to show why:

1. In the first example to put **labels on the top of each column** more space would be necessary for the label text; meaning **the columns would have to be further apart**, that in turn would cause more horizontal eye movement - which isn't pleasing to the reader, It's arguably sufficiently understood what the scores and post counts mean. (But good point on over and under labeled, I hadn't heard the term before.)

   The top user list per tag has **20 items occupying 1,5 vertical screens**
2. In the second example (tags page in user profile) the problem is that if you have a lot of tags in your profile **the list becomes so long you won't see any labels because the header line on the top goes off-screen** quickly and you still have to do more scrolling.

   The tags page in the user profile has **52 labels that occupy about 5 vertical screens.**

[image: screenshot of tags page in user profile]

##### The above screenshot is 3 full vertical screens collated (and it's only around half way through the list). If you remove the labels from each line (placing them at the top instead), you'll still have around 5 vertical screens worth of scrolling, but the labels will be quickly be off-screen.

Comment: You could make the labels static of course, and the list itself scrollable.

Comment: @Luuklag what you mean by "labels static" and "itself scrollable" isn't clear. (I don't see any such example on the rest of the site.)

Comment: No there isn't any such example on the site yet, but it could be a very good solution. It's applied all around us. Instead of making the entire page scroll like currently, you can have a window where 10-15 tags fit, and make the list within that window scrollable, so that the labels are always visible.

Comment: You can think of it as the answer editor, the buttons are always visible, even though your text might be really long, the content just scrolls in the box.

Comment: @Luuklag I think it would be a very bad solution and there's good reason the site doesn't use it in any element - most sites that come to mind don't. (The editor doesn't compare to regular site elements.)

Comment: _If_ the horizontal eye movement required _for a single word_ is unacceptable in the Top Users table, 
I don't understand how so much completely unnecessary empty horizontal space in the Tags table can be justified.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace that [was asked over 100 times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372698) during the change to responsive design. ATM it is what it is, several users requested variations of 2 columns, etc... But it's not a trivial change, one single list does look good overall, what layout would you propose to change from 1 column list? (That'd be a significant change beyond the scope of the current post.)

Comment: @Luuklag: A better example would be the left sidebar.

Comment: Having tables with data that takes up more than a single screen is a seperate problem. I like the idea of static header labels, but another option would be to just divide the table into multiple pages.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace FYI, I didn't check but this isn't a table, it's a CSS grid or flexbox, and it's already divided into multiple pages.

Comment: @Justin not the sidebars still wouldn't make a better example because although they float they don't overlay to any other elements. (Again there's no such example on the entire site, that I can think of, currently.)

Comment: I agree with @Luuklag and the OP that making the table fixed-height and adding inner scrolling instead would be a better solution than scrolling the page itself. It is, indeed, a very common UI technique that table headers are made static (or sticky but it's support is finicky). SE's Stacks framework also natively supports that. Example: [gif of a part of the UI from one of my userscripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpl9E.gif).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine do SE's officially supported browsers all have the feature? Doesn't it potentially break legacy or less used browsers? It's been a concern of SE to keep the site working for users with lower end systems, metered bandwith's, etc... So Luuklag's claim is easy to make but requires expertise to back up (you saying it's "finicky" confirms my suspicion). Does it fit well with the current state of SE's CSS? Personally I wouldn't like the scrolling window (its use would be mostly for tags page so I'm not convinced that alone is worth the trouble).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine ok and I just saw the included screenshot and I really dislike sites with those scrolling fixed windows. Scrolling a box doesn't make it much better, and in this case I uhhh don't see any gains at all.

Comment: @bad_coder admittedly, the example I gave has an important limitation that makes such scrolling desirable: it has to fit potentially a huge list of information into a small space available for a popup on a page. This is much less of a problem for full pages the discussion is about, but I wanted to demo that it can be successfully done within SE's framework and [current state of CSS](https://caniuse.com/css-sticky) [provided one doesn't care about Opera Mini and knows to work around a certain kink with `auto` on Safari] (although other methods can be used to get the desired effect too). [1/2]

Comment: The "sticky" approach *does* break on legacy browsers, but other approaches can be applied as mentioned that do not have this drawback (on an off-note, as you know, SE doesn't care much about legacy browsers officially, though, and will break for them either way). Anyways, frankly, the gist of the issue that lead SE to label every cell, in my view, lies in the low information density after the redesign - if the individual rows were to take less vertical space (or used multi-column layout for wider ), we wouldn't be having the discussion in the first place as users wouldn't [2/3]